# Can I use groovy in play framework's application.conf?

Tags: groovy, playframework

I've seen in [this comment](https://github.com/playframework/play/pull/480#issuecomment-4437750) and elsewhere hints that there's a way to use groovy tags in application.conf to make more dynamic configuration, but I haven't seen any real documentation describing this.

Specifically, I'm interested in setting configuration variables according to hostname and System Properties.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

So I finally looked at t[he code that reads the conf file](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/Play.java#L396). The support for groovy tags is minimal, and basically allows the following usages:

- `${application.path}` gets interpolated as the current application base path
- `${play.path}` gets interpolated as the play framework base path
- Any other string in the form of `${key}` is checked against the system properties, and if not available, checked against the environment variables

This can be used together with the `@include` functionality to achieve my use case like this:

- Under the conf directory, I have the usual `application.conf`, as well as `specific/dev001.conf`, `specific/test001.conf`, `specific/prod001.conf` etc. each of the specific files contains configuration for the specific host.
- In `application.conf` I have a line that says `@include.hostspecific=specific/${HOSTNAME}.conf`
- Before running `play run` I make sure to set the HOSTNAME environment variable.

With Linux + bash:

```
export HOSTNAME=$(uname -n)
play run
```

On windows:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %i IN (`hostname`) DO SET HOSTNAME=%i
play run
```

Note that play will not load if there's a missing include file, so I now need a conf file for every machine I run it on.